# Xcode 6.4 simulator freezes sporadically

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator

My simulator (any iOS version) can sporadically freeze any application I work. Tried "Reset content and settings" option on simulator. Clean my projects derived data in Xcode version 6.4 and so on. Simulator keeps freezing sometimes and I need to restart the application then it works for a while. Mac OS X version 10.10.5. I tried Xcode 7 beta 4 before this problem appears however this happen on another mac where no any beta system was installed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide specific details.  You should take a spindump when your app is spinning to see what it is blocked on.